# bounced emails are in the contact table but not in the bounce report

Tags: civimail, bounce

I have drupal 7.69 with civicrm 5.24.3 successfully running on siteground.  I am running under windows 10 and have multiple browsers installed, all current (EDGE, Chrome, FireFox, Opera). Running under Siteground managed PHP version 7.3.  I have VERP set in civicrm and a valid bounce email (which works as far as getting bounced messages into my contact table).  I can search the contact table and find 36 bounces ("b.").  All that is fine - but NO bounces show up in my bounce reports ?

Comment: Do you mean CiviCRM 5.23.4? Also could provide some more info about what you mean by 'my contact table'?

Comment: Yes - I meant civicrm 5.3.4 - sorry.  And my contact table is the civicrm_contact table.

Comment: Just curious how did you find 36 bounces ("b.")?

Comment: I searched in the civicrm_contact table for all display names beginning with ".b"